# how to programming the code in Xcalc.js

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function Operator(input) {
  this.operator = input;
  if (!input) {
    console.log("Operator has no input.");
  }
  this.solve = function(segment1, segment2, x) {
    var v1 = segment1.coefficient;
    if (segment1.type=="variable") {
      v1 = x;
    }
    var v2 = segment2.coefficient;
    if (segment2.type=="variable") {
      v2 = x;
    }
    if (this.operator=="+") {
      return new Segment(v1 + v2);
    } else if (this.operator=="-") {
      return  new Segment(v1 - v2);
    } else if  (this.operator=="*") {
      return  new Segment(v1 * v2);
    } else if (this.operator=="/") {
      return  new Segment(v1 / v2);
    } else if (this.operator=="^") {
      return  new Segment(Math.pow(v1, v2));
    }
  };
}//Class for special functions
function MathFunction(input) {
  this.f=input;
  if (!input) {
    console.log("Math function has no input.");
  }
 this.solve = function(segment) {
    var v = segment.coefficient;
    if (this.f=="sin") {
      return new Segment(Math.sin(v));
    } else if (this.f=="cos") {
      return new Segment(Math.cos(v));
    } else if (this.f=="tan") {
      return new Segment(Math.tan(v));
    } else if (this.f=="asin") {
      return new Segment(Math.asin(v));
    } else if (this.f=="acos") {
      return new Segment(Math.acos(v));
    } else if (this.f=="atan") {
      return new Segment(Math.atan(v));
    } else if (this.f=="abs") {
      return new Segment(Math.abs(v));
    }
  };
}
//Class for a segment of math (a container)
function Segment(input) {
  this.sections = [];
  this.type="section";
  this.operator=0;
  this.coefficient=0;
  this.mathFunction=0;
  this.variable="";
  var removeBrackets = function(value) {
    if (!value) return "";

    //While there are brackets around the string
    while (value.substr(0, 1)=="(" && value.substr(value.length-1, 1)==")") {          var openBrackets=1;
      //See if the end bracket closes the opening bracket or not
      for (var i=1; i<value.length&&openBrackets>0; i++) {
        if (value.substr(i, 1)=="(") openBrackets++;
        if (value.substr(i, 1)==")") openBrackets--;
      }
      i-=1;

      //If it corresponds to different brackets, do nothing
      if (openBrackets!==0 || i!=value.length-1) {
        break
     pue.substr(i, 1)=="(") {
          openBrackets++;
        } else if (value.substr(i, 1)==")") {
          openBrackets--;
        }

        if (i==index) {

          //If no brackets are open (and if the operator is actually - and not just a minus sign), break the loop.
       
    var r=0;
    if (trig=="sin") {
      r=/(a)?sin/g;
    } else if (trig=="cos") {
      r=/(a)?cos/g;
    } else if (trig=="tan") {
      r=/(a)?tan/g;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
    for (matches=r.exec(value); matches; matches=r.exec(value)) if (RegExp.$1 != "a") index=matches.index;
    var inBrackets=true;
    while (inBrackets && index!=-1) {
      var openBrackets=0;

      //Find how many brackets are opened or closed at a given point in the string
      for (var i=0; i<value.length; i++) {
        if (value.substr(i, 1)=="(") {
          openBrackets++;
        } else if (value.substr(i, 1)==")") {
          openBrackets--;
        }

        if (i==index) {

          //If no brackets are open (and if the operator is actually - and not just a minus sign), break the loop.
          if (openBrackets===0) {
            inBrackets=false;
            break;

          
      }
    }
    str+="<div class='answer'>= " + this.solve().coefficient + "</div>";
    str+="</div>";
    return str;
  };
  //constructor
  if (input!==undefined) {
    if (typeof(input)=="string") {
      //Remove excess whitespace
      input = input.replace(/\s/g, "");

      //get rid of unnecessary brackets surrounding the section
      input = removeBrackets(input);
      
      //Find the last instance of each operator in the string
      var addition = findLast("+", input);
      var subtraction = findLast("-", input);
      var division = findLast("/", input);
      var exponent = findLast("^", input); //Find the first exponent, since those work in reverse
      var bracket1 = findLast("(", input);

      var sin = findLastTrig("sin", input);
      var cos = findLastTrig("cos", input);
      var tan = findLastTrig("tan", input);
      var asin = findLast("asin", input);
      var acos = findLast("acos", input);
      var atan = findLast("atan", input);
      var abs = findLast("abs", input);
      var multiplication = findLast("*", input);
      var multiplication2 = findMultiplicationBrackets(input); //Find brackets that are the same as multiplication
      var functionMultiplication = -1;
      if (sin>multiplication) functionMultiplication=sin;
      if (cos>multiplication) functionMultiplication=cos;
      if (tan>multiplication) functionMultiplication=tan;
      if (asin>multiplication) functionMultiplication=asin;
      if (acos>multiplication) functionMultiplication=acos;
      if (atan>multiplication) functionMultiplication=atan;
      if (abs>multiplication) functionMultiplication=abs;

      //Push back each half of the equation into a section, in reverse order of operations
      if (addition != -1 && (subtraction == -1 || addition>subtraction)) {
        this.sections.push(new Segment(input.substring(0, addition)));
        this.sections.push(new Segment(input.substring(addition+1)));
        this.operator = new Operator("+");
      } else if (subtraction != -1) {
        if (subtraction>0) {
          this.sections.push(new Segment(input.substring(0, subtraction)));
        } else {
          this.sections.push(new Segment(0));
        }
        this.sections.push(new Segment(input.substring(subtraction+1)));
        this.operator = new Operator("-");
      } else if (functionMultiplication >0 && functionMultiplication > multiplication && functionMultiplication > division) {
        this.sections.push(new Segment(input.substring(0, functionMultiplication)));
        this.sections.push(new Segment(input.substring(functionMultiplication)));
        this.operator = new Operator("*");
      } else if (multiplication2 != -1 && (division == -1 || multiplication>division) && (multiplication == -1 || multiplication2>multiplication)) {
        this.sections.push(new Segment(input.substring(0, multiplication2)));
        this.sections.push(new Segment(input.substring(multiplication2)));
        this.operator = new Operator("*");
      } else if (multiplication != -1 && (division == -1 || multiplication>division)) {
        this.sections.push(new Segment(input.substring(0, multiplication)));
        this.sections.push(new Segment(input.substring(multiplication+1)));
        this.operator = new Operator("*");
      } else if (division != -1) {
        this.sections.push(new Segment(input.substring(0, division)));
        this.sections.push(new Segment(input.substring(division+1)));
        this.operator = new Operator("/");
      } else if (exponent != -1) {
        this.sections.push(new Segment(input.substring(0, exponent)));
        this.sections.push(new Segment(input.substring(exponent+1)));
        this.operator = new Operator("^");
      } else if (sin != -1 && (cos == -1 || sin>cos) && (tan == -1 || sin>tan) && (asin == -1 || sin>asin) && (acos == -1 || sin>acos) && (atan == -1 || sin>atan) && (abs == -1 || sin>abs)) {
        this.sections.push(new Segment(input.substring(sin+3)));
        this.mathFunction = new MathFunction("sin");
        this.type = "function";
      } else if (cos != -1 && (tan == -1 || cos>tan) && (asin == -1 || cos>asin) && (acos == -1 || cos>acos) && (atan == -1 || cos>atan) && (abs == -1 || cos>abs)) {
        this.sections.push(new Segment(input.substring(cos+3)));
        this.mathFunction = new MathFunction("cos");
        this.type = "function";
      } else if (tan != -1 && (asin == -1 || tan>asin) && (acos == -1 || tan>acos) && (atan == -1 || tan>atan) && (abs == -1 || tan>abs)) {
        this.sections.push(new Segment(input.substring(tan+3)));
        this.mathFunction = new MathFunction("tan");
        this.type = "function";
      } else if (asin != -1 && (acos == -1 || asin>acos) && (atan == -1 || asin>atan) && (abs == -1 || asin>abs)) {
        this.sections.push(new Segment(input.substring(asin+4)));
        this.mathFunction = new MathFunction("asin");
        this.type = "function";
      } else if (acos != -1 && (atan == -1 || acos>atan) && (abs == -1 || acos>abs)) {
        this.sections.push(new Segment(input.substring(acos+4)));
        this.mathFunction = new MathFunction("acos");
        this.type = "function";
      } else if (atan != -1 && (abs == -1 || atan>abs)) {
        this.sections.push(new Segment(input.substring(atan+4)));
        this.mathFunction = new MathFunction("atan");
        this.type = "function";
      } else if (abs != -1) {
        this.sections.push(new Segment(input.substring(abs+3)));
        this.mathFunction = new MathFunction("abs");
        this.type = "function";
      } else if (bracket1 != -1) {
        var openBrackets=1;
        for (var i=bracket1+1; i<input.length&&openBrackets>0; i++) {
          if (input.substr(i, 1)=="(") openBrackets++;
          if (input.substr(i, 1)==")") openBrackets--;
        }
        if (openBrackets===0) {
          var bracket2=i-1;
          if (bracket1>0) this.sections.push(new Segment(input.substring(0, bracket1)));
          if (bracket2-bracket1!=1) this.sections.push(new Segment(input.substring(bracket1+1, bracket2)));
          if (bracket2!=input.length-1) this.sections.push(new Segment(input.substring(bracket2+1)));
          this.operator = new Operator("*");
        } else {
          console.log("Brackets nesting error: " + input);
        }

      //If there are no operators, just push the input itself
      } else {
        var xLocation=input.toLowerCase().indexOf("x");
        if (xLocation!=-1) {
          if (xLocation>0) {
            this.sections.push(new Segment(input.substring(0, xLocation)));
            this.sections.push(new Segment("x"));
            this.operator=new Operator("*");
          } else {
            this.variable="x";
            this.type="variable";
          }
        } else {
          this.coefficient = parseFloat(input);
          this.type = "value";
        }
      }
    } else if (typeof(input)=="number") {
      this.coefficient = input;
      this.type = "value";
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Segment has no input.");
  }
}
//One point on a graph
function Point(x, y) {
  this.x = x || 0;
  this.y = y || 0;
}
//MathFunction to create graphs
function Graph(value, width, height, rangeX, rangeY) {
  var autoRange=false;

  //Default params
  if (rangeX===undefined) {
    rangeX=10;
  }
  if (rangeY===undefined) {
    autoRange = true;
  }
  //Properties
  this.expression = new Segment(value);
  this.points = [];
  this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  this.canvas.width=width || 400;
  this.canvas.height=height || 400;
  this.min=undefined;
  this.max=undefined;
  this.x1 = 0-Math.abs(rangeX);
  this.x2 = 0+Math.abs(rangeX);
  this.y1 = 0-Math.abs(rangeY);
  this.y2 = 0+Math.abs(rangeY);
  var startMouse = new Point(0, 0);
  var mousePos = new Point(0, 0);
  var timer=0;
  var stage=0;
  var img=0;
  var magnitudeX = 0;
  var magnitudeY = 0;
  //Gets minimum y value in the set of points
  this.getMin = function() {
    if (this.min===undefined) {
      if (this.points.length>0) {
        var min = this.points[0].y;
        for (var i=1; i<this.points.length; i++) {
          if (this.points[i].y<min) min = this.points[i].y;
        }
        this.min=min;
        return min;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    } else {
      return this.min;
    }
  };

  //Gets maximum y value in the set of points
  this.getMax = function() {
    if (this.max===undefined) {
      if (this.points.length>0) {
        var max = this.points[0].y;
        for (var i=1; i<this.points.length; i++) {
          if (this.points[i].y>max) max = this.points[i].y;
        }
        this.max=max;
        return max;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    } else {
      return this.max;
    }
  };
  //Updates the points and graph
  this.update = function() {
    var accuracy = (this.x2-this.x1)/this.canvas.width;
    this.points = [];
    for (var i=this.x1; i<=this.x2; i+=accuracy) {
      this.points.push(new Point(i, this.expression.result(i)));
    }
    if (autoRange) {
      if (this.getMax()-this.getMin()>100000) {
        this.y1=-100;
        this.y2=100;
      } else {
        this.y1=this.getMin()-5;
        this.y2=this.getMax()+5;
      }
      autoRange = false;
    }

    magnitudeX = Math.ceil(Math.log(this.x2-this.x1));
    magnitudeY = Math.ceil(Math.log(this.y2-this.y1));

    this.redraw();
  };

  var drawAxes = function(_x1, _x2, _y1, _y2, redraw) {
    stage.strokeStyle="#bdc3c7";
    stage.fillStyle="#bdc3c7";
    var limit=0;
    var i=0;

    //Draw the y axis if it is in the view
    if (0>=_x1-30 && 0<=_x2+30) {
      stage.lineWidth=2;
      stage.beginPath();
      stage.moveTo(this.canvas.width/2-(((_x2+_x1)/2)/(_x2-_x1))*this.canvas.width, 0);
      stage.lineTo(this.canvas.width/2-(((_x2+_x1)/2)/(_x2-_x1))*this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
      stage.closePath();
      stage.stroke();
      stage.textAlign = "right";
      stage.textBaseline="middle";

      stage.lineWidth=1;
      limit = (Math.abs(_y2)>Math.abs(_y1))?Math.abs(_y2):Math.abs(_y1);
      for (i=0; i<=limit; i+=Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log(_y2-_y1) / Math.LN10))/4) {
        if (i===0) continue;
        if (i<=_y2+50) {
          if (redraw || (i>=this.y2-50)) {
            stage.beginPath();
            stage.moveTo(this.canvas.width/2-(((_x2+_x1)/2)/(_x2-_x1))*this.canvas.width-5, this.canvas.height-((i-_y1)/(_y2-_y1))*this.canvas.height);
            stage.lineTo(this.canvas.width/2-(((_x2+_x1)/2)/(_x2-_x1))*this.canvas.width+5, this.canvas.height-((i-_y1)/(_y2-_y1))*this.canvas.height);
            stage.closePath();
            stage.stroke();
            stage.fillText(""+(Math.round(i*100)/100), this.canvas.width/2-(((_x2+_x1)/2)/(_x2-_x1))*this.canvas.width-8, this.canvas.height-((i-_y1)/(_y2-_y1))*this.canvas.height);
          }
        }

        if (i>=_y1-50) {
          if (redraw || (-i<=this.y1+50)) {
            stage.beginPath();
            stage.moveTo(this.canvas.width/2-(((_x2+_x1)/2)/(_x2-_x1))*this.canvas.width-5, this.canvas.height-((-i-_y1)/(_y2-_y1))*this.canvas.height);
            stage.lineTo(this.canvas.width/2-(((_x2+_x1)/2)/(_x2-_x1))*this.canvas.width+5, this.canvas.height-((-i-_y1)/(_y2-_y1))*this.canvas.height);
            stage.closePath();
            stage.stroke();
            stage.fillText(""+(Math.round(-i*100)/100), this.canvas.width/2-(((_x2+_x1)/2)/(_x2-_x1))*this.canvas.width-8, this.canvas.height-((-i-_y1)/(_y2-_y1))*this.canvas.height);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    //Draw the x axis if it is in the view
    if (0>=_y1-50 && 0<=_y2+50) {
      stage.lineWidth=2;
      stage.beginPath();
      stage.moveTo(0, this.canvas.height/2+(((_y2+_y1)/2)/(_y2-_y1))*this.canvas.height);
      stage.lineTo(this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height/2+(((_y2+_y1)/2)/(_y2-_y1))*this.canvas.height);
      stage.closePath();
      stage.stroke();
      stage.textAlign = "center";
      stage.textBaseline="top";

      stage.lineWidth=1;
      limit = (Math.abs(_x2)>Math.abs(_x1))?Math.abs(_x2):Math.abs(_x1);
      for (i=0; i<=limit; i+=Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log(_x2-_x1) / Math.LN10))/4) {
        if (i===0) continue;
        if (i<=_x2+50) {
          if (redraw || (i>=this.x2-50)) {
            stage.beginPath();
            stage.moveTo(((i-_x1)/(_x2-_x1))*this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height/2+(((_y2+_y1)/2)/(_y2-_y1))*this.canvas.height-5);
            stage.lineTo(((i-_x1)/(_x2-_x1))*this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height/2+(((_y2+_y1)/2)/(_y2-_y1))*this.canvas.height+5);
            stage.closePath();
            stage.stroke();
            stage.fillText(""+(Math.round(i*100)/100), ((i-_x1)/(_x2-_x1))*this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height/2+(((_y2+_y1)/2)/(_y2-_y1))*this.canvas.height+8);
          }
        }

        if (i>=_x1-50) {
          if (redraw || (-i<=this.x1+50)) {
            stage.beginPath();
            stage.moveTo(((-i-_x1)/(_x2-_x1))*this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height/2+(((_y2+_y1)/2)/(_y2-_y1))*this.canvas.height-5);
            stage.lineTo(((-i-_x1)/(_x2-_x1))*this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height/2+(((_y2+_y1)/2)/(_y2-_y1))*this.canvas.height+5);
            stage.closePath();
            stage.stroke();
            stage.fillText(""+(Math.round(-i*100)/100), ((-i-_x1)/(_x2-_x1))*this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height/2+(((_y2+_y1)/2)/(_y2-_y1))*this.canvas.height+8);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }.bind(this);

  //Updates the canvas
  this.redraw = function() {
    if (this.points.length>1) {
      stage.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
      stage.lineCap="round";
      var offsetY = -this.y1;
      drawAxes(this.x1, this.x2, this.y1, this.y2, true);
      //Draw all the points
      stage.strokeStyle="#2980b9";
      stage.lineWidth=1;
      stage.beginPath();
      stage.moveTo(0, this.canvas.height-((this.points[0].y+offsetY)/(this.y2-this.y1))*this.canvas.height);
      for (var i=1; i<this.points.length; i++) {
        if (Math.abs((this.canvas.height-((this.points[i].y+offsetY)/(this.y2-this.y1))*this.canvas.height)-(this.canvas.height-((this.points[i-1].y+offsetY)/(this.y2-this.y1))*this.canvas.height))<=this.canvas.height) {
          stage.lineTo((i/this.points.length)*this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height-((this.points[i].y+offsetY)/(this.y2-this.y1))*this.canvas.height);
        }
        stage.moveTo((i/this.points.length)*this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height-((this.points[i].y+offsetY)/(this.y2-this.y1))*this.canvas.height);
      }
      stage.closePath();
      stage.stroke();

      img = stage.getImageData(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    } else {
      console.log("Not enough points to graph.");
    }
  };
  this.setRange = function(_x1, _x2, _y1, _y2) {
    this.x1=_x1;
    this.x2=_x2;
    this.y1=_y1;
    this.y2=_y2;
    this.update();
  };
var getMousePos = function(evt) {
      var rect = this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
      var root = document.documentElement;
      
      // return relative mouse position
      var mouseX = evt.clientX - rect.left - root.scrollLeft;
      var mouseY = evt.clientY - rect.top - root.scrollTop;
      
      return new Point(mouseX, mouseY);
  }.bind(this);

  var startDrag = function(event) {
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", dragMouse, false);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", endDrag, false);
    this.canvas.removeEventListener("mouseover", startMouseOver, false);
    this.canvas.removeEventListener("mousemove", moveMouse, false);
    startMouse = getMousePos(event);
  }.bind(this);

  var redrawLine = function() {
    var offsetX = ((mousePos.x-startMouse.x)/this.canvas.width)*(this.x2-this.x1);
    var offsetY = ((mousePos.y-startMouse.y)/this.canvas.height)*(this.y2-this.y1);
    this.setRange(this.x1-offsetX, this.x2-offsetX, this.y1+offsetY, this.y2+offsetY);
    startMouse = mousePos;
  }.bind(this);

  var dragMouse = function(event) {
    stage.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    mousePos = getMousePos(event);
    var newx1 = this.x1-((mousePos.x-startMouse.x)/this.canvas.width)*(this.x2-this.x1);
    var newx2 = this.x2-((mousePos.x-startMouse.x)/this.canvas.width)*(this.x2-this.x1);
    var newy1 = this.y1+((mousePos.y-startMouse.y)/this.canvas.height)*(this.y2-this.y1);
    var newy2 = this.y2+((mousePos.y-startMouse.y)/this.canvas.height)*(this.y2-this.y1);

    if (Math.abs(newx1-this.x1)>this.canvas.width/2 || Math.abs(newy1-this.y1)>this.canvas.height/2) {
      redrawLine();
    } else {
      drawAxes(newx1, newx2, newy1, newy2, false);
      stage.putImageData(img, mousePos.x-startMouse.x, mousePos.y-startMouse.y);
    }
    }.bind(this);

  var endDrag = function(event) {
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", dragMouse, false);
    document.removeEventListener("mouseup", endDrag, false);
    this.canvas.addEventListener("mouseover", startMouseOver, false);
    this.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMouse, false);
    mousePos = getMousePos(event);

    var offsetX = ((mousePos.x-startMouse.x)/this.canvas.width)*(this.x2-this.x1);
    var offsetY = ((mousePos.y-startMouse.y)/this.canvas.height)*(this.y2-this.y1);
    this.setRange(this.x1-offsetX, this.x2-offsetX, this.y1+offsetY, this.y2+offsetY);
  }.bind(this);

  var startMouseOver = function(event) {
    this.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMouse, false);
    this.canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", endMouseOver, false);
  }.bind(this);

  var moveMouse = function(event) {
    stage.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    stage.putImageData(img, 0, 0);
    mousePos = getMousePos(event);
    var offsetY = -this.y1;

    //Draw the coordinate
    stage.fillStyle="#2980b9";
    stage.beginPath();
    stage.arc(mousePos.x, this.canvas.height-((this.points[Math.round(mousePos.x/this.canvas.width*this.points.length)].y+offsetY)/(this.y2-this.y1))*this.canvas.height, 4, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    stage.closePath();
    stage.fill();
    stage.fillStyle="#000";
    stage.strokeStyle="#FFF";
    stage.lineWidth=4;
    stage.textBaseline="alphabetic";
    var txt="(" + (Math.round(this.points[Math.round(mousePos.x/this.canvas.width*this.points.length)].x*100)/100).toFixed(2) + ", " + (Math.round(this.points[Math.round(mousePos.x/this.canvas.width*this.points.length)].y*100)/100).toFixed(2) + ")";

    if (mousePos.x<stage.measureText(txt).width/2+2) {
      stage.textAlign = "left";
    } else if (mousePos.x>this.canvas.width-stage.measureText(txt).width/2-2) {
      stage.textAlign = "right";
    } else {
      stage.textAlign = "center";
    }
    stage.strokeText(txt, mousePos.x, -10+this.canvas.height-((this.points[Math.round(mousePos.x/this.canvas.width*this.points.length)].y+offsetY)/(this.y2-this.y1))*this.canvas.height);
    stage.fillText(txt, mousePos.x, -10+this.canvas.height-((this.points[Math.round(mousePos.x/this.canvas.width*this.points.length)].y+offsetY)/(this.y2-this.y1))*this.canvas.height);
  }.bind(this);
  var endMouseOver = function(event) {
    this.canvas.removeEventListener("mousemove", moveMouse, false);
    this.canvas.removeEventListener("mouseout", endMouseOver, false);
    stage.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    stage.putImageData(img, 0, 0);
  }.bind(this);
  //Returns the canvas element
  this.getCanvas = function() {
    return this.canvas;
  };
  //If canvas drawing is supported
  if (this.canvas.getContext) {
    //Get the canvas context to draw onto
    stage = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    stage.font = "12px sans-serif";
    this.canvas.style.backgroundColor="#FFF";
    //Make points
    this.update();
    this.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startDrag, false);
    this.canvas.addEventListener("mouseover", startMouseOver, false);
  } else {
    console.log("Canvas not supported in this browser.");
    this.canvas = document.createElement("div");
    this.canvas.innerHTML="Canvas is not supported in this browser.";
  }
}
ntById("wrapper").className="";
    var timer = setTimeout(function() {
      var graph = XCalc.graphExpression(input, 400, 400);
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById("result").appendChild(graph.getCanvas());
      document.getElementById("wrapper").className="solved";
    }, 800);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<div class='error'>Error: Improperly nested brackets. Remember to only use round brackets and close all opened brackets.</div>";
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("simplify").addEventListener("click", simplifyText);
  simplifyText();
};
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="exmath.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<div id="top"><h1>Maths equation plotter</h1>
   f(x) = <input type="text" value="(x+4)^2*(x-6)+60sinx" id="input" /><input type="button" value="Graph" id="simplify" />
  </div>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="result"></div>
  

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have some code in XCalc.js i want to support particular equation in(algebra equation,quadratic,linear,nonlinear equation) in based on equation how to programming in XCalc.js and how to show the steps based on equation so please help me to improve my code.refer this link:https://github.com/davepagurek/XCalc

Comment: please any one can help me

Comment: @markE please help me  any suggestion to improve my code.